# DataMapper query - last year, last month etc

Tags: sql, ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I use sinatra web framework and DataMapper.

I have code:

```
@wdata = Data.all(:date => ((DateTime.now - @interval.to_i)..DateTime.now))
```

When I want Data from last 24 hours I use @interval = 1, last 7 days @interval = 7.

How I should get data from e.g. last month or last year? Month can have 31, 30, 28 or 29 days I would like to distinguish this. I would e.g. get data from june last year, last two months, etc.

I searched in web for some tutorial, but I found only for ActiveRecord. :(

Comment: what's last month given today is 14/7/2012? Would it be 1/6/2012-30/6/2012 or 13/6/2012-14/7/2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there is more elegant solution, but you can do such ranges manually

```
d = DateTime.today
p = d.prev_month
py = d.prev_year
last_month = Data.all(:date => (DateTime.new(p.year, p.month)..DateTime.new(d.year, d.month))
last_year = Data.all(:date => (DateTime.new(py.year)..DateTime.new(d.year))
```